# Bridge.NET - How to make a hyperlink

Tags: javascript, c#, html, bridge.net

I am using [Bridge (C# to JS Compiler)](https://bridge.net/) to make a website.

I cannot figure out how to create a hyperlink (the `a` HTML tag) using C#. You can make the other HTML tags (examples below):

```
HTMLDivElement div1 = new HTMLDivElement();
HTMLButtonElement button1 = new HTMLButtonElement();
HTMLParagraphElement para1 = new HTMLParagraphElement();
```

There seems to be no way *(I have searched Google and the Bridge Documentation/Forums)* to make a hyperlink?
Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Somewhat alarming is many of the types that appear in the nuget package aren't actually declared in the github repo(only tests): https://github.com/bridgedotnet/Bridge/search?q=HTMLButtonElement&unscoped_q=HTMLButtonElement

Comment: Have you tried `HTMLLinkElement`?

Comment: @AaronLS The `HTMLLinkElement` is generally used to include a .css file. To create a hyperlink, an `HTMLAnchorElement` would be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>Full Disclosure: I heard of bridge the first time in this moment <sub>(but it seems to be exciting)</sub></sub>.

I think, you are searching for the wrong word. In HTML hyperlinks are called Anchors, hence the `<a>`.

After searching for it, I found this [post](https://forums.bridge.net/forum/community/help/5314-replace-part-of-dom), talking about `HTMLAnchorElement`.

[aschoenebeck](https://forums.bridge.net/member/215-aschoenebeck) has added an example [there](https://deck.net/16dac2885f12734e6e2d1e63809944a9):

```
using Bridge.Html5;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var body = Document.Body;
        HTMLDivElement msg = new HTMLDivElement { Id = "MsgPanel" };
        HTMLAnchorElement linkbtn = new HTMLAnchorElement
        {
            Href = "#",
            InnerHTML = "Click",
            OnClick = (ev) =>
            {
                HTMLDivElement msgpanel =
                    Document.GetElementById<HTMLDivElement>("MsgPanel");
                msgpanel.InnerHTML = "MyText";
            }
        };
        body.AppendChild(linkbtn);
        body.AppendChild(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Here's a similar sample, but using the `Retyped.dom` library instead of `Bridge.Html5` => https://deck.net/b01b7eba2e8939be8ac6d90cf0e30105

Comment: Thank you! I did not know that hyperlinks were called Anchors.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry "a" hyperlink not path of HTML5... Path of HTML..

Create your own.:

Document.CreateElement("a");